# ¿Como Llamar un procedimiento almacenado MYSQL desde PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Me gustaría saber como llamar un procedimiento almacenado de `Mysql` desde `PHP`, lo eh intentado de varias formas pero de ninguna me ah dado y eh buscado en Internet y tampoco.
lo eh intentado como una consulta simple asi:

```
$cal = $_POST[`calcular`];
if (isset($cal)) {
   $query = "call CalificaMejor();";
   $datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte de manera correcta es importante que adiciones a la pregunta el código que haz utilizado y los errores que se te han presentado.

Comment: eh intentado haciendo como si fuera una consulta simple pero poniendo call asi  $query = "call procedimiento();";
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);

Comment: puedes darle a tu pregunta, editar y adicionar el código utilizado.

Comment: te retorna algún mensaje de error?

Comment: nada, no me sale nada. eso es lo extraño.

Comment: @ElMagodeas, intenta agregando esta línea justo al final: `if (!$datos) { printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conexion)); }`

Comment: No tampoco no me dice nada ni warning nada.

Comment: Cuando ejecutas el procedimiento en mysql si te arranca de manera correcta?

Comment: esas comillas del $post, arreglalas por favor. Reemplaza $cal = $_POST[`calcular`]; por $cal = $_POST['calcular'];

Comment: Realiza un var_dump($query) después de esta línea $query = "call CalificaMejor();"; a ver que te arroja

Comment: Ya me funciono gracias eran las comillas y con var_dump($query).
Muchas Gracias

Comment: como se hace soy nuevo aquí en este foro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reemplaza

`$cal = $_POST[`calcular`];`

por

```
$cal = $_POST['calcular'];
```

Tienes mal las comillas y por eso no arroja ningún error. Además es una buena práctica probar las variables siempre con **var_dump();** o utilizar alguna **extensión** de **"depuración"** php como **firePHP** por ejemplo.

Eso es todo. Un Saludo

Comment: gracias amigo :).

Comment: De nada bro. Me alegra que te sirviera. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Para los que no les de, aquí les dejo el código de como hice para al dar clic en calcular me ejecutara el procedimiento almacenado.

```
if (isset($_POST['calcular'])) {
                            //calcular es el nombre del boton
                            $stmt = $conexion->prepare("CALL CalculaMejor();");
                            $stmt->execute();
                            if ($stmt == false) {
                                echo("Error! Al calcular mejor.");
                                $stmt->close();
                            } else {
                                echo("Exito! Calculo exitoso.");
                                $stmt->close();
                            }
                        }
```